# Blender Rotations vs OpenGL Rotations

Tags: c#, opengl, matrix, blender, 3d-modelling

I am writing a custom script for exporting Blender models and animation into a game that runs using OpenGL.

I am aware that Blender uses a Z-up system whereas OpenGL in my game uses a Y-up system. I can easily fix the model mesh and bone positions with a rotation around the X axis of -π/2, which renders the model correctly.

However in Blender a bone on my character's leg that is parallel with the floor has an euler X rotation of 0, and a bone that is perpendicular to the floor has an euler X rotation of -π/2 (or π/2).

In-game, a character's leg that is parallel to the floor has an euler X rotation of -π/2 (or π/2) and a bone that is perpendicular to the floor has a rotation of 0.

Here, the model's left leg is parallel with the floor with the same XYZ euler rotation as the left leg in Blender (which is perpendicular to the floor):

[image: Player Model and Bones]

The blender export script for bone rotations at each frame is:

```
for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end + 1):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(f);
    bpy.context.scene.update();

    for i in range(len(arm.pose.bones)):
        bone = arm.pose.bones[i]
        out.write(str(boneIDs[bone.name]) + ","); # ID of the bone
        out.write(VecToStringComma(bone.matrix.to_euler())) # bone rotation

    out.write("\n")
```

And loading it in C# the bone rotation matrix is recomposed with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= frameCount; i++)
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    var parts = r[read].Split(',');
    read++;

    for (int p = 0; p < parts.Length - 1; p += 4)
    {
        FrameDeform fd = new FrameDeform();
        fd.DeformerID = int.Parse(parts[p]);

        Vector3 rot = new Vector3(double.Parse(parts[p + 1]), double.Parse(parts[p + 2]), double.Parse(parts[p + 3]));
        fd.Rotation = Matrix4.CreateRotationX(rot.X) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(rot.Y) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(rot.Z);

        frame.FrameDeforms.Add(fd);
    }

    anim.Frames.Add(frame);
}
```

Frame 0 in Blender looks like this:

[image: Blender model frame 0]

Frame 0 in-game looks like this:

[image: In-Game model frame 0]

I am aware that at the moment I am not applying any alterations to the rotation values, however I can see that the legs are following the right movement path in-game, but on the incorrect axis.

Rotating the rotation values by -π/2 around the X axis does not help, as the X values remain unchanged.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated as I have been struggling with this issue for quite a while.

**Update**

When loading the model I apply no rotations around the X axis. Instead, at run-time I apply a rotation of -π/2 around the X axis, which happens in the shader:

```
vec3 pos = (zMat * bones[id] * vec4(aPosition, 1.0)).xyz
```

However this gives me the following result (when only animating the torso):

[image: Run-Time transformation]

Comment: Every bone in an armature has it's own axis orientation, blender allows you to 'spin' a bone with it's roll setting (in edit mode). You want to "rotate" the whole armature as a single object so that the rest position of each bone is in the right place, from there the animation uses the same local translations for each bone. You will only need to alter any animation that may be applied to the armature object.

Comment: Each bone in bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose has a rotation_axis_angle of (0,0,1,0). I've updated my question above with my attempts at this.

Comment: By doing a -90º roation, is the Z-axis facing the right way for the coordinate system? I know 3DMax gives you the option to swap Y-Z axes on export. Did you try simply swapping the Y and Z axes?